# build tree with a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

how to make tree with the following multidimensional array?

the child items have a non-zero **parentID**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [title] => zzz
            [parentID] => 0
            [parentName] => 
            [section] => articles
            [sort] => 0
            [level] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 7
                    [title] => 7
                    [parentID] => 6
                    [parentName] => 
                    [section] => articles
                    [sort] => 0
                    [level] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 8
                            [title] => 8
                            [parentID] => 7
                            [parentName] => 
                            [section] => articles
                            [sort] => 0
                            [level] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => ØªØ³Øª
            [parentID] => 0
            [parentName] => 
            [section] => articles
            [sort] => 0
            [level] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [title] => 4
                    [parentID] => 1
                    [parentName] => 
                    [section] => articles
                    [sort] => 0
                    [level] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [title] => 5
                    [parentID] => 1
                    [parentName] => 
                    [section] => articles
                    [sort] => 0
                    [level] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

if i want to show items by **id**, i need following result :

```
6
-7
--8
1
-4
-5
```

my attempt :

```
foreach ($array as $category)
{
    $dash = str_repeat("-", array_depth($category));
    echo $dash . $category['id'];
}
```

Comment: Could you please put php array itself instead of var_dump in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of

```
function render_node($node, $indent = '') {
    $indent .= '-';
    echo $indent . $node[0]['id'];
    for($i = 1; $i < array_length($node); $i++) {
        render_node($node[$i], "$indent-");
    }
 }
```

Not tested, but hope you get the idea. There may be an off by one error and some other oddities.